# Pandas Dataframe not returning results for 1 string value in a column using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord bot for a webapp that I am planning to make in the future that utilizes Pandas to make a dataframe that stores all of the possible drops from an instance in WoW. I have created this bot to take user input, such as "!loot cloth" to store 'cloth' as an argument and pass it to a .loc function to search the 'itemtype' column for 'cloth'. I am running into an interesting bug where this does not work if I search for 'leather'.

This is an example of the leather portion of my dataframe:

```
    itemname                            itemtype    itemslot    stat1    stat2    source
--  ----------------------------------  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  ----------------------------
32  Corpuscular Leather Greaves         leather     feet        crit     mastery  Carapace of N'Zoth
33  Cord of Anguished Cries             Leather     waist       haste    mastery  Dark Inquisitor Xanesh
34  Gloves of Abyssal Authority         leather     hands       haste    mastery  Drest'agath
35  Spaulders of Aberrant Allure        leather     shoulders   azerite           Il'gynoth, Corruption Reborn
36  Belt of Braided Vessels             Leather     waist       haste    vers     Il'gynoth, Corruption Reborn
37  Stygian Guise                       leather     head        azerite           Maut
38  Boots of Manifest Shadow            leather     feet        haste    mastery  Maut
39  Pauldrons of the Great Convergence  leather     shoulders   azerite           N'Zoth the Corruptor
40  Bracers of Dark Prophecy            leather     wrists      crit     haste    Prophet Skitra
41  Macabre Ritual Pants                leather     legs        crit     vers     Prophet Skitra
42  Gibbering Maw                       leather     head        azerite           Ra-den the Despoiled
43  Wristwraps of Volatile Power        leather     wrists      haste    mastery  Shad'har the Insatiable
44  Chitinspine Gloves                  leather     hands       vers     mastery  The Hivemind
45  Darkheart Robe                      leather     chest       azerite           Vexiona
46  Onyx-Imbued Breeches                leather     legs        vers     mastery  Wrathion, the Black Emperor
```

As you can see, these items are stored as 'leather' in the 'itemtype' column, with 2 saved as 'Leather' in an attempt to debug the issue.

```
if message.content.startswith('!loot'):
        arg = message.content.lstrip('!loot ')
        if arg == '1h':
            await message.channel.send('`' + tabulate(df1h, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple') + '`')
        elif arg == '2h':
            await message.channel.send('`' + tabulate(df2h, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple') + '`')
        else:
            result = df1.loc[df1['itemtype'] == arg]
            await message.channel.send('`' + tabulate(result, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple') + '`')
```

This is the chunk of code I am using to handle the user input and to manipulate my dataframe into giving me the information that the user is requesting.  My issue is when someone types '!loot leather' the output is:

```
itemname    itemtype    itemslot    stat1    stat2    source
----------  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  --------
```

But when they send the command '!loot Leather', the result is this:

```
    itemname                 itemtype    itemslot    stat1    stat2    source
--  -----------------------  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  ----------------------------
33  Cord of Anguished Cries  Leather     waist       haste    mastery  Dark Inquisitor Xanesh
36  Belt of Braided Vessels  Leather     waist       haste    vers     Il'gynoth, Corruption Reborn
```

For some reason, it will not return results when the rows are saved with lowercase leather in the itemtype column. Keep in mind, this works as intended for the other variables in the itemtype column, such as 'cloth', 'plate', 'mail', 'accessories', etc. It would be possible for me to just manipulate their input into capitalizing the first letter but I feel like that is a bandaid solution.

Any thoughts? I am pretty new to python, < 1 month of total experience, but this issue is rather puzzling to me and I couldn't seem to get any help from the /r/learnpython subreddit and the python discord. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code seems like it should work. My guess is a data error with the content in the dataframe. Have you checked that the string 'leather' that is stored in the dataframe doesn't have a trailing space ('leather ') or something like that that could result in a failed string equality?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same. Can you try using ```result = df1.loc[df1['itemtype'] == (arg.strip())]```?

Comment: @Steve , My dataframe data is populated by connecting to a MySQL server that I have set up and fetches information from a table. I went and checked and made sure there are no leading or trailing spaces, no weird characters, no numbers. Could it be that one instance of leather isn't being saved as a string and its throwing the rest of the results out? It's a really weird bug seeing as all of the other variables work, except for leather.

Comment: @EstebanQuiros , I just tried that and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What happens if you compare the string 'leather' to arg? What's the result?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm kind of stumped. Sounds like some debugging is in order. Maybe `print(arg)` after assigning it to ensure that it has the value that you are expecting. Also, try inspecting `df1` in the debugger (or variable explorer, etc) to make sure that it actually has the rows in it that you are expecting (e.g. 'leather' rows are actually present to begin with before filtering). Good luck!

Comment: @Steve I tried print(arg) in my statement and when I enter the command !loot leather, arg returns as 'eather', why would that be? When doing !loot Leather, it returns 'Leather' as you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is lstrip removes all the characters you specify that are on the left of the string. 'l' is part of the list of characters you are specifying. lstrip receives a list of characters not a particular string you want to remove. Try this:

```
#import re
#This way we use a regular expression to make sure it matches perfectly
arg = re.sub('^!loot ','',message.content)
```

Instead of this part of your code:

```
arg = message.content.lstrip('!loot ')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much. I didn't realize .strip() doesn't take a string, the documentation for it made it seem like you pass it a string to remove common leaders to user input.

Answer (score 0):

The string method `.lstrip` removes the leading characters that are supplied to it. So, in your case, it removes all `!`, `l`, `o`, `t` and  characters from the left most part of the string on which it is acting. This is why the `l` of leather is being removed.

To achieve your desired result of removing the substring `'!loot '`, use `.replace('!loot ', '')`:

`example = '!loot leather'
example_stripped = example.lstrip('!loot ')
print(example_stripped)  # 'eather'
example_replaced = example.replace('!loot ', '')
print(example_replaced)  # 'leather'`